# Windows mobile API's Reference link?

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-mobile-6, windows-mobile-5.0

Please tell me what are API's are available in windows mobile.tell me the reference links for that.

Answer (score 0):

you have to download the free Microsoft Windows Mobile SDKs: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5389 (see bottom for other SDKs than for WEH652).

Windows Mobile devices support a subset of Standard Win32 API plus some Mobile specific APIs.

Depending on the device OS version, they come with Dotnet Compact Framework 1.0, 2.0 or 3.5 pre-installed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w6ah6cw1.aspx

If you need other informations, you should be more specific in your question.

Comment: Hi Thnaks,For windows phone 7 i found the following URL for list of API's available.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626516(v=vs.92).like that i need windows mobile API's list...